# Displaying various format text on android

Tags: android, android-webview, text-formatting

Which widgets can I use to display text like below image?
I think about **Webview**, it displays type 1 and 2 ( see image ) so good, but what about type 3 ? 
I have lots of pages like that, so it must spend much time to create html.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have many pages like this, I would advice you to use `WebView`.

Your 3rd part can be achieved by a placing it in a `<code>...</code>` block, with `CSS` like,

```
code {
  background:#F8F8FF; 
  border:black dashed 1px; 
  padding:6px
}​
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks you but seem it is not expected solution that I hope

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly you are looking for? :)

Comment: Even if you manage to display it in TextView with `Html.fromHtml()` (as in *@Panda*'s answer) you may need to manipulate each block with added `HTML` tags on it. I believe it's better to create full `HTML` pages and show it in a `WebView` will be more easy for you.

Comment: I hope another solution, sir. Both your and Panda's solution also have to create HTML format. So, I have to create html and css for all device. Should I work harder or think better solution ?

Comment: AFAIK, for such screens with lot of formatting, `HTML` is the best & fast option. Try using some **WYSIWYG** editor to get it done fast. :)

Comment: thanks for suggesting me using WYSIWYG. I have tried to use it via thread on some forums before, it's not good.
But I have just found a better site : https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor.
It could help someone :)

p/s: about my thread's flag, i can not add flag as android-webview, text-formatting, etc.... :)

Comment: Another option is using a `markdown-to-html` editor/convertor. which will help you reduce a lot of manual work. :)

Comment: I searched but I did not find any markdown-to-html editor that better than wysiwyg-editor. thanks you :)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you can use something like

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sup>2</sup>"));
```

or see if this will help: 
[here](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html#selectingtext)

Comment: you write the html in fromHtml()